# Showing Seekbar progress on touch the seekbar control

Tags: android

I have a seekbar control and whenever i seek the control the value is shown only after the seek is finished,i need to get the value as soon the control is touched.

The code on onStopTrackingTouch is given below :

```
textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
```

Seek bar control is shown [here](http://www.kompyooter.com/?qa=52/showing-seekbar-progress-on-touch-the-seekbar-control) which display value only after seek completes

Comment: But you also have  __onStartTrackingTouch__

Comment: @NikMyers onStartTrackingTouch didnt gave me the result ,i tried that

Comment: If you just want the seekbar values to be seen, you could try out some UI libraries for the seekbar https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: @powerpoint2 Demo for seekbar-control using touch https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/SeekBar-Swipecontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , This may help you

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

@Override       
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}       

@Override       
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());     
}       

@Override       
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     


   textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

}       
});
```