# Get SeekBar touch position (without progress change)

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, seekbar

I have a simple discrete `SeekBar` indicating a progression from 0 to 10.

The progression of the `SeekBar` is defined programmatically, so I disabled touch events in order to prevent the user from changing its current position:

```
mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

However, **I need to get the position the user touched on the `SeekBar`** (regardless of its current progress).

Basically, if the user touches the first "dot", he goes to one activity, if he touches the second, he goes to another, etc... But none of these actions should change the current state of the `SeekBar`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30165937/5110595)

Comment: I tried using onSeekBarChangeListener, but none of the methods are called if I override onTouch like in my snippet. And if I remove this snippet, the progress of the SeekBar can then be changed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way to achieve what I wanted to, so I had to find a small workaround.

I just added a second, invisible `SeekBar` on top of the other one, used only to handle touch events using `onSeekBarChangedListener`.

To make it transparent, I used:

```
android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
```

The other `SeekBar` is used as before, only to display progress information. That way I have to separate behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

To get the position of the place where you touched in the seekbar use

int a=seekbar.getProgress().
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvFAo.png)

```
 setTemperature.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            int a= seekbar.getProgress()

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did't it this way:

```
  seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps